# Change color of bar graph after reopen figure file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have a lot of graphs as a fig file and want to change the font size and color of these in a function. In this example, it's a bar graph.

This is my code:

```
function changeproperties(fontsize, figdata)
   openfig(figdata);
   set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize);
   set(gca,'FaceColor','r');
   saveas(gcf,'graph.pdf','pdf');
end
```

It changes the fontsize, but not the bar color.

The error message is this:

> Error using `matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set`
>       There is no `FaceColor` property on the `Axes` class.
>
> Error in `changeallfonts` (line 4)
>         ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ `set(gca,'FaceColor','r');`

`gcf` also doesn't work. What is the fault?

Comment: You may find that you have to use `get(gca,'Children')` to get the bar objects

Answer (score 3):

You say that you open saved .fig files, so you need to get the right handle to the bar object (children of the axes) **posteriorly** (i.e. after it already exists, and *not* while creating it). A quite robust way to do that is to use [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
function changeproperties(fontsize,figdata)
   openfig(figdata);
   set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize);
   b = findobj(gca,'Type','Bar'); % returns a handle to the bar
   set(b,'FaceColor','r'); % changes all bars in the current axes
   saveas(gcf,'graph.pdf','pdf');
end
```

This way, if your axes include other objects, they won't be affected.

Also, if you use the function to open multiple figures, you might want to add a [`close`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/close.html?s_tid=doc_ta) command to it as well (`close(gcf)`), otherwise it's harder to guarantee that the current axes are indeed what you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

`Fontsize` is the property of axes; `FaceColor` is not.
Enter `gca` in the command window to see that. `FaceColor` is the property of its children as also [hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299939/change-color-of-bar-graph-after-reopen-figure-file-in-matlab/45300836#comment77561479_45299939) by [*Wolfie*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie).

---

You need the handle of `bar` instead.

An [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#examples):

```
y = [75 91 105 123.5 131 150 179 203 226 249 281.5];
h=bar(y);
set(h,'FaceColor','r');   %or h.FaceColor='r' for MATLAB R2014 and later
```

[image]

Since you are using fig files here, you don't have the handle of `bar` so you can use the handle of axes like this:

```
ax=gca;
set(ax.Children,'FaceColor','r');
```